# Batch file to open multiple ip-based links in new tabs

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to make a batch file to open multiple links, in multiple tabs.
The links are ip-based and I would like to open a range in multiple tabs.
eg. start "Chrome" c:\path\to\chrome.exe https://192.168.1.1-50

So I'm looking for something where I can just change the end variable, the last IP in the range without having to add a single line for each individual address, 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2...192.168.1.50 etc etc

I'm not sure if this is possible or not but it would surely be great to get some input on this.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. What I've tried is;
start "Chrome" "C:\path\to\chrome.exe" https://192.168.1.1-50

I've also tried using | as a separator but to no avail.
I can get it to work if I add lines for each address, but I want to avoid having to do that.

Comment: Also, the ability to downvote a question without any kind of reasoning behind it, is the reason why I try to avoid stackexchange etc. Sure, it may be scripting 101, but by asking the question I am obviously stating that I was unable to get it to work. 
So asking for help gets downvotes without even a hint as to why a sincere question is considered not worthy.

Comment: You got downvoted because your question made no indication that you made any effort whatsoever into trying to solve the problem yourself. Visit the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for advice about how to ask a question and what kinds of questions to avoid. The way you've worded your question makes it sound like you're asking us to write code **for** you, which is a huge no-no.

Comment: I surely do not want to get into a war of words here because that would not really amount to anything.
I respectfully disagree with your assessment that I gave no indication, if you read my comment I did post what I had tried to do. Also, isn't downvoting without posting a reason basically the same thing as I was downvoted for in the first place?
But again, I thank all for taking the time to give me opinions and answers. Me posting here was only about seeking help, and not getting into a war of words.

Comment: **`for` loops *are* absolute basic programming knowledge**. So yes, you did *not* demonstrate any *effort* on your own. Yes, *please* avoid Stackexchange with such questions.

Comment: since you ask so nicely :)...I shall still ask, because there are still people around who'd rather help, than spew counter-productive, fatuous nonsense. As per the fact that I did get an answer and it didn't require any finger pointing. 
Nice use of italic and bold by the way, maybe you can teach me how to some time. I bid adieu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /l %%a in (1 1 50) do start "chrome" "c:\path\to\chrome.exe" 198.168.1.%%a
```

Use a `for /l` command to iterate over a numeric set. For each value starting at 1 up to 50 in steps of 1, execute the indicated command. For each value in the set, the command after the `do` clause will be executed with `%%a` referencing the current value.